# SheetJS (js-xlsx) in browser: read a workbook from a Blob

Tags: typescript, filereader, sheetjs

I am running into a wall trying to use SheetJS to build a Workbook object from a `Blob`, as opposed to a client event like a drag-and-drop or file input element event. The latter two are covered in the [documentation's examples](https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx#parsing-workbooks) but I lack the JS-fu required to translate backward from the `Blob` that I have, through the `FileReader` events and into the `XLSX.read()` API.

Given a `Blob` in a browser, how can this be accomplished, or can it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do

```
var wb = XLSX.read(await blob.arrayBuffer(), { type: "array" });
```

Comment: Unfortunately I'm a bit separated from this code right now, but I will try to verify this when I can. Thanks for taking a look at this question! Always surprises me when anything older than a few days gets a look.

Comment: Quite simple, I faced the same issue, found your question with no answer. After a few tries on my own (documentation is very limited) I found a solution and wanted to share it just in case it would save someone half an hour.

Comment: Thanks @FranckJeannin. I was struggling with this for an hour.

Answer (score 0):

I'm saving to XLSX with this code:

```js
import XLSX from 'xlsx'
import { saveAs } from 'file-saver'

export function saveAsXlsx({ fileName = 'export', worksheets }: Params) {
  const blob = getXlsxBlob(worksheets)
  saveAs(blob, `${fileName}.xlsx`)
}

export function getXlsxBlob(worksheets: Worksheet[]) {
  const workbook = XLSX.utils.book_new()

  worksheets.forEach(({name, header, body}) => {
    const worksheet = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(body, {header})
    XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(workbook, worksheet, name)
  })

  const workbookOutput = XLSX.write(workbook, {
    type: 'binary',
    bookType: 'xlsx'
  })
  return new Blob([stringToArrayBuffer(workbookOutput)], {
    type: 'application/octet-stream'
  })
}

interface Params {
  fileName?: string
  worksheets: Worksheet[]
}

export interface Worksheet<T extends string = string> {
  name: string
  header: T[]
  body: Record<T, string | number>[]
}

function stringToArrayBuffer(string: string) {
  const buffer = new ArrayBuffer(string.length)
  const view = new Uint8Array(buffer)
  for (let i = 0; i < string.length; i++) view[i] = string.charCodeAt(i) & 0xff
  return buffer
}
```

Then I'm trying to test that code. I decided not to mess with real files, so I extracted most of the complexity to `getXlsxBlob` and focused on testing that part.

Here's the code I tried to test with:

```js
import xlsx from 'xlsx'

import { getXlsxBlob, Worksheet } from './saveAsXlsx'

const people: Worksheet = {
  name: 'People',
  header: ['Name', 'Age'],
  body: [
    {
      Name: 'John Doe',
      Age: 37
    },
    { Name: 'Jane Doe', Age: 35 }
  ]
}

const cars: Worksheet = {
  name: 'Cars',
  header: ['Brand', 'Model', 'Color'],
  body: [
    { Brand: 'Toyota', Model: 'RAV4', Color: 'red' },
    { Brand: 'SAAB', Model: '9-3', Color: 'blue' }
  ]
}

test('getXlsxBlob', async () => {
  const blob = getXlsxBlob([people, cars])
  
  const arrayBuffer = await blob.arrayBuffer()
  const workbook = xlsx.read(arrayBuffer, {type: 'array'})
  expect(workbook.SheetNames).toEqual(['People', 'Cars'])
  expect(xlsx.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook.Sheets['People']))
    .toEqual(people.body)
  expect(xlsx.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook.Sheets['Cars'])).toEqual(cars.body)
})
```

It blows up with

```
    TypeError: blob.arrayBuffer is not a function

      26 | test('getXlsxBlob', async () => {
      27 |   const blob = getXlsxBlob([people, cars])
    > 28 |   const arrayBuffer = await blob.arrayBuffer()
         |                                  ^
```

(would be curious to figure out why, if you know - please share in the comments)

But resorting to `FileReader` helps:

```js
test('getXlsxBlob', async () => {
  // ...
  const arrayBuffer = await readAsArrayBuffer(blob)
  // instead of
  // const arrayBuffer = await blob.arrayBuffer()
  // ...
})

function readAsArrayBuffer(blob: Blob) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    const reader = new FileReader()
    reader.onload = (event) => {
      resolve(event.target?.result)
    }
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob)
  })
}
```